# arguments when using the PHP Facebook API Graph library?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am trying to pull some statuses in json format from Facebook's Graph API. Since i am using PHP, so I went for the following library.

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php

I saw the example, and the class requires some arguments upon instantiation, and I just don't know what they are:

```
// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '344617158898614',
  'secret' => '6dc8ac871858b34798bc2488200e503d',
));
```

And also from the Graph API Explorer I see the access_token, but this PHP library doesn't mention it at all, I thought I need the access_token to make requests, don't I? I hope someone can clear things up for me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you require an `access_token` to query on behalf of user on Facebook, it can either be an App access token or User access token.  If the user authorizes your app, with required permission which in your case would be `read_stream` permission,  then you can obtain his access token and query for status updates. The default access token is your App access token which can access only public data.

Also I would suggest you to to over the [PHP SDK documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/) for getting started with it.